# How to keep StringBuilder to append twice the same line

Tags: c#, logging, stringbuilder

I'm using StringBuilder and File.AppendAllText to create a log for my application. But I can't understand why it always priunts the same line twice - except for the milliseconds that are slightly different. I put two `sb.Clear()` Here is my code. Am I missing something i can't find?

```
if (_bRealLog == true)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Clear();
    if (_bAppend == true)
    {
        sb.AppendLine();
    }
    sb.Append($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,FFF")} [SY] {_szLabel} {_szLogMessage}");
    File.AppendAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.szDirectoryPath + "\\" + "log.log", sb.ToString());
    sb.Clear();
}
```

[EDIT]

What I get is this

```
2018-12-06 15:36:08,585 [SY] INFO   Node aquisition and loading of cables
2018-12-06 15:36:08,589 [SY] INFO   Node aquisition and loading of cables
2018-12-06 15:36:30,414 [SY] NOTICE 43 cables are loaded
2018-12-06 15:36:30,419 [SY] NOTICE 43 cables are loaded
```

When I should get that

```
2018-12-06 15:36:08,585 [SY] INFO   Node aquisition and loading of cables
2018-12-06 15:36:30,414 [SY] NOTICE 43 cables are loaded
```

Comment: [`AppendAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2) concats the new text to the already available

Comment: So should I just use Append ?

Comment: You should tell what you actually want. This code writes only one message to the file. But if you call it a second time you would get another one.

Comment: Why instantiate a new StringBuilder then immediately clear it?

Comment: @maccettura I was trying to see if that was the reason, I forgot to delete the first clearing.

Comment: @Rango I just edited my question

Comment: Did you debug and test this method is not calling twice?

Comment: @GregoireRouet: you need to show the code which calls this code, because this isn't the reason for the issue. It will write only one message to the file.

Comment: did you check to see if the log file log.log has the entries twice?

Comment: I found the issue, and posted an answer! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing in this code that would duplicate the line. You must be running this block of code twice. Set a breakpoint immediately after `File.AppendAllText()` and open your text file to see if the line is there twice before resuming.

Answer (score 0):

I have found my issue, which was pretty dumb actually. I put a condition for an `InvokeRequired` and I placed log part outside the else condition which obviously made it run twice. Thanks and sorry for your time, it is greatly appreciated.

```
 public void WriteLog(string _szMessage, bool _bRealLog, bool _bAppend = true, string _szLogMessage = "", string _szLabel = "")
    {
        if (this.rtbLogs.InvokeRequired)
        {
            PrintLogDelegate d = new PrintLogDelegate(WriteLog);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { _szMessage, _bRealLog, _bAppend, _szLogMessage, _szLabel });
        }
        else
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(rtbLogs.Text))
            {
                rtbLogs.AppendText($"{_szMessage}");
                rtbLogs.ScrollToCaret();
            }
            else
            {
                rtbLogs.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + $"{_szMessage}");
                rtbLogs.ScrollToCaret();
            }

            if (_bRealLog == true)
            {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Clear();
                if (_bAppend == true)
                {
                    sb.AppendLine();
                }
                sb.Append($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,FFF")} [SY] {_szLabel} {_szLogMessage}");
                File.AppendAllText(Properties.Settings.Default.szDirectoryPath + "\\" + "log.log", sb.ToString());
                sb.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```